# Objective-c mile/km conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, unit-conversion

In my iPhone application, the user can change the unit (km or mile) in the preferences.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"km" forKey:@"distanceUnit"];
```

or

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"mile" forKey:@"distanceUnit"];
```

I save the distance only in km in my **Core-Data.** I work with **int**. So every time I get the distance i do the following:

```
if ([unit isEqualToString:@"km"]) {
} else {
    intTotalKM = intTotalKM * 0.621371192;
}
```

And when saving the distance, I do the following:

```
if ([unit isEqualToString:@"km"]) {
} else {
    intTotalKM = intTotalKM / 0.621371192;
}
```

For example, without changing my distance, when I save and get it, I loose 1 or 2 km/miles.

I loose precision because of **0.621371192** and because I'm using only **int**. I don't want to use double values. Do you have any ideas of how to deal with this problem?

Edit: I wonder if there is any other way of conversion more appropriate for my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the largest distance that you need to store? Are we talking about distances on Earth, or do you need larger distances?

Comment: You could consider store your distance and unit in a dictionary and save it into `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: largest distance is 999999 km.

Comment: Not your problem, but a simpler approach is to have a global value of some sort that you set on startup to be either 0.621... or 1.0.  Then you don't need to code the test of "unit" every time.

Comment: You're going to lose about a half km of precision every time you cast the floating point result of the multiply or divide to an int.  You can maybe cut your losses in half by keeping the internal number as float/double and only casting to int when you store the value in Core Data.  But why don't you want to use a floating-point number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the loss of precision that you have by converting the number **one time** is acceptable, then I would just quit converting back and forth every time that you display/save it, and only convert, if needed, when the value is entered by the user.

So in other words, just like in your user defaults, only ever have the value in memory represent km.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    intTotalKM = [textField.text intValue];

    if ([unit isEqualToString:@"mile"]) {
        intTotalKM = intTotalKM / 0.621371192;
    }
}
```

Note that this conversion is **only done once** when the user enters a new value.

To display the value to the user, you would convert the value to miles if needed.  When you save the value, you simply save intTotalKM without doing any conversion since it is always stored in KM.

Otherwise, you should store the value in such a way that you won't have this loss of precision.  By storing the decimal portion of the number (using a double), by saving as a different unit (like meters - my personal favorite) or by storing the unit and using native values, all as suggested in other answers here.

Answer (score 3):

The only loss-less solution is to store the distance in the native units. Add a single-character column designating the units in which the distance is expressed, and store a code (say, `'K'` for `km` and `'M'` for miles) along with the actual distance.

If adding a column is not an option, you can put the units in the upper bits of the number that you store: since the largest distance in your app is `2^20`, you can use the remaining 12 bits of the number to encode the units in which the distance is expressed. Use `dist & 0xFFFFF` to extract the actual distance, and `dist >> 20` to extract the units code (`1` for `km`, `0` for `mi`).

Answer (score 2):

If you really wish to stay with integers and maintain precision use smaller units. With your maximum requirement of 999999km then if your integers are 32-bit you can store the value in meters and adjust your conversion to produce yards. If your integers are 64-bit then you can can use cm or even mm, but you probably don't need to go that far. This is how some financial calculations are done, e.g. a $1.59 is not stored as 1.59 but as 159.

Comment: I would personally just store the distance in meters, which should give you plenty of precision for conversion to either miles or km as needed.  Very simple approach to take!  +1

Answer (score 1):

You've answered the question yourself: you lose precision because you're using integers... You don't have much of a choice. Either you change to double, or you stick with int and inaccurate values...

Comment: Well, he could compromise and use float.

Comment: You're right. I wanted to know if is there any other way of conversion more appropriate for my situation?

Comment: You can use meters instead of kilometers.

Comment: @Yossarian -- True -- One could use my scheme of a conversion factor and have it be either 1000.0 or 621.37...   You'd still lose something if you switched back and forth between km and miles, but the values would be accurate to a meter if you stuck with one or the other.